# Reading form array

Tags: php, mysql

I have this previous post where I need to change my HTML form to accept an array. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109074/form-submit-not-working) has the full details of the code.

So I changed all forms accordingly, such as:

```
<select name="camera_type[]">
```

But now I'm stuck on how to run the update query. Now that I store everything in an array I obviously can't use my query as is.  Here is a post that seems to be exactly what I need, but I'm not sure I understand:  [Update MySQL table with an Array using Foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818712/update-mysql-table-with-an-array-using-foreach)

Any further help on this is appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting when you run the UPDATE query? It looks like you have all of the code on the other post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` [loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on the submitted value. Then you can iterate over the entire array and construct queries as you please.

For example: You have a $_POST['camera_type'] variable which is an submitted from the browser. In your php script do the following.

```
foreach($_POST['camera_type'] as $value) {
  //do your processing.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. I've added the foreach loop on the submitted value.  Just not sure how to construct the update query.  Do I update in each loop?  Seems...inefficient?

Comment: Agreed, it seems inefficient, but it'd the only way. Unless you want to go down the track of creating a single UPDATE query and using CASE arguments to set the values for the various feeds based on the tuple's ID field.

Comment: @TomPepernic Tho may be inefficient its a general way. The `POST['camera_type']` holds *ONLY* those which are submitted, so it wont have redundant values. Hence its better.

Answer (score 1):

To help understand looping through an array and running `UPDATE` queries check this out:

```
// first setup your MySQLi connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

// disable autocommit for transactions
$db->autocommit(false);

// **EDIT** forgot to escape input data. fixed now. note the mysqli_real_escape_string() and int type casting
foreach ($_POST['camera_type'] as $type) {
    // assuming 'id' is set in the POST array
    $query = sprintf(
        'UPDATE table SET column = "%s" WHERE id = %d', 
        $db->real_escape_string($type), 
        (int) $_POST['id']
    );
    $db->query($query);
}

// commit transactions (or commit the updates that were run) and then close
$db->commit();
$db->close();
```

Comment: hmm oops missed that one. fixed. Thanks! ...but why was this downvoted?

Comment: because of sql injection which still persists. you have to either cast the id to int instead of escaping OR quote it.

Comment: Ok touche. Thanks for commenting! I fixed it now. :) Did I miss anything else? (by the way, I _swear_ I always validate all my data before running queries lol)

Comment: data validation and query composing are different matters.

Comment: true. to me that's just semantics, but I guess I use the term loosely and perhaps shouldn't. thanks for the help, though!

Comment: I am taking validation as data-specific routine, say, email validation. while query composing should be quite contrary - data-irrelevant, allowing any kind of data into query while making it safe way.